# Need to get the particular attribute/value from JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, nestjs

I have a JSON and I need to get **SKU** attribute value as a result array. The SKU attribute will be inside of **shipping** and OFSUC arrays. So I am trying to get those values efficiently using a **filter** or **map** function in JS but I don't know how to iterate more than one array.

**My JSON Object**

```
{
"id": 103,
"consignments": [
    {
        "pickups": [],
        "shipping": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "first_name": "Sabareesh",
                "line_items": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "order_id": 103,
                        "product_id": 86,
                        "variant_id": 66,
                        "order_pickup_method_id": 0,
                        "order_address_id": 4,
                        "name": "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
                        "name_customer": "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
                        "name_merchant": "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
                        "sku": "ABS",
                        "upc": "",
                        "type": "physical",
                        "base_price": "225.0000",
                        "price_ex_tax": "225.0000",
                        "price_inc_tax": "270.0000",
                        "price_tax": "45.0000",
                        "base_total": "225.0000",
                        "total_ex_tax": "225.0000",
                        "total_inc_tax": "270.0000",
                        "total_tax": "45.0000",
                        "weight": "1.0000",
                        "width": "10.0000",
                        "height": "10.0000",
                        "depth": "10.0000",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "base_cost_price": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_tax": "0.0000",
                        "is_refunded": false,
                        "quantity_refunded": 0,
                        "refund_amount": "0.0000",
                        "return_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_name": "",
                        "base_wrapping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_message": "",
                        "quantity_shipped": 0,
                        "event_name": null,
                        "event_date": "",
                        "fixed_shipping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "ebay_item_id": "",
                        "ebay_transaction_id": "",
                        "option_set_id": null,
                        "parent_order_product_id": null,
                        "is_bundled_product": false,
                        "bin_picking_number": "",
                        "external_id": null,
                        "fulfillment_source": "",
                        "brand": "",
                        "gift_certificate_id": null,
                        "applied_discounts": [],
                        "product_options": [],
                        "configurable_fields": [],
                        "discounted_total_inc_tax": "270.0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "order_id": 103,
                        "product_id": 94,
                        "variant_id": 68,
                        "order_pickup_method_id": 0,
                        "order_address_id": 4,
                        "name": "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
                        "name_customer": "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
                        "name_merchant": "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
                        "sku": "OCG",
                        "upc": "",
                        "type": "physical",
                        "base_price": "31.4600",
                        "price_ex_tax": "31.4600",
                        "price_inc_tax": "37.7500",
                        "price_tax": "6.2900",
                        "base_total": "31.4600",
                        "total_ex_tax": "31.4600",
                        "total_inc_tax": "37.7500",
                        "total_tax": "6.2900",
                        "weight": "1.0000",
                        "width": "0.0000",
                        "height": "0.0000",
                        "depth": "0.0000",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "base_cost_price": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_tax": "0.0000",
                        "is_refunded": false,
                        "quantity_refunded": 0,
                        "refund_amount": "0.0000",
                        "return_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_name": "",
                        "base_wrapping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_message": "",
                        "quantity_shipped": 0,
                        "event_name": null,
                        "event_date": "",
                        "fixed_shipping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "ebay_item_id": "",
                        "ebay_transaction_id": "",
                        "option_set_id": null,
                        "parent_order_product_id": null,
                        "is_bundled_product": false,
                        "bin_picking_number": "",
                        "external_id": null,
                        "fulfillment_source": "",
                        "brand": "Sagaform",
                        "gift_certificate_id": null,
                        "applied_discounts": [],
                        "product_options": [],
                        "configurable_fields": [],
                        "discounted_total_inc_tax": "37.7500"
                    }
                ],
                "items_total": 2,
                "items_shipped": 0,
                "shipping_method": "Free Shipping",
                "base_cost": 0,
                "cost_ex_tax": 0,
                "cost_inc_tax": 0,
                "cost_tax": 0,
                "cost_tax_class_id": 2,
                "base_handling_cost": 0,
                "handling_cost_ex_tax": 0,
                "handling_cost_inc_tax": 0,
                "handling_cost_tax": 0,
                "handling_cost_tax_class_id": 2,
                "shipping_zone_id": 2,
                "shipping_zone_name": "Qatar"      
            }
        ],
        "downloads": [
            {
                "line_items": [
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "order_id": 103,
                        "product_id": 104,
                        "variant_id": 72,
                        "order_pickup_method_id": 0,
                        "order_address_id": 0,
                        "name": "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
                        "name_customer": "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
                        "name_merchant": "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
                        "sku": "OFSUC",
                        "upc": "",
                        "type": "digital",
                        "base_price": "41.3600",
                        "price_ex_tax": "41.3600",
                        "price_inc_tax": "49.6300",
                        "price_tax": "8.2700",
                        "base_total": "41.3600",
                        "total_ex_tax": "41.3600",
                        "total_inc_tax": "49.6300",
                        "total_tax": "8.2700",
                        "weight": "0.0000",
                        "width": "0.0000",
                        "height": "0.0000",
                        "depth": "0.0000",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "base_cost_price": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_tax": "0.0000",
                        "is_refunded": false,
                        "quantity_refunded": 0,
                        "refund_amount": "0.0000",
                        "return_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_name": "",
                        "base_wrapping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_message": "",
                        "quantity_shipped": 0,
                        "event_name": null,
                        "event_date": "",
                        "fixed_shipping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "ebay_item_id": "",
                        "ebay_transaction_id": "",
                        "option_set_id": null,
                        "parent_order_product_id": null,
                        "is_bundled_product": false,
                        "bin_picking_number": "",
                        "external_id": null,
                        "fulfillment_source": "",
                        "brand": "OFS",
                        "gift_certificate_id": null,
                        "applied_discounts": [],
                        "product_options": [],
                        "configurable_fields": [],
                        "discounted_total_inc_tax": "49.6300"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "email": {
            "gift_certificates": []
        }
    }
]
```

}

**Expected result:**
["OCG", "ABS", "OFSUC"]

Comment: _"My JSON Object"_ No, it's either a JSON encoded string or a JavaScript Object. What have you tried before resorting to asking a question that's probably been asked more than a few times on [so]?

Comment: `Expected result: ["OCG", "ABS", "OFSUC"]` ... why is that expected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
const jsonObject={id:103,consignments:[{pickups:[],shipping:[{id:4,first_name:"Sabareesh",line_items:[{id:5,order_id:103,product_id:86,variant_id:66,order_pickup_method_id:0,order_address_id:4,name:"[Sample] Able Brewing System",name_customer:"[Sample] Able Brewing System",name_merchant:"[Sample] Able Brewing System",sku:"ABS",upc:"",type:"physical",base_price:"225.0000",price_ex_tax:"225.0000",price_inc_tax:"270.0000",price_tax:"45.0000",base_total:"225.0000",total_ex_tax:"225.0000",total_inc_tax:"270.0000",total_tax:"45.0000",weight:"1.0000",width:"10.0000",height:"10.0000",depth:"10.0000",quantity:1,base_cost_price:"0.0000",cost_price_inc_tax:"0.0000",cost_price_ex_tax:"0.0000",cost_price_tax:"0.0000",is_refunded:!1,quantity_refunded:0,refund_amount:"0.0000",return_id:0,wrapping_id:0,wrapping_name:"",base_wrapping_cost:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_ex_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_inc_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_message:"",quantity_shipped:0,event_name:null,event_date:"",fixed_shipping_cost:"0.0000",ebay_item_id:"",ebay_transaction_id:"",option_set_id:null,parent_order_product_id:null,is_bundled_product:!1,bin_picking_number:"",external_id:null,fulfillment_source:"",brand:"",gift_certificate_id:null,applied_discounts:[],product_options:[],configurable_fields:[],discounted_total_inc_tax:"270.0000"},{id:14,order_id:103,product_id:94,variant_id:68,order_pickup_method_id:0,order_address_id:4,name:"[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",name_customer:"[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",name_merchant:"[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",sku:"OCG",upc:"",type:"physical",base_price:"31.4600",price_ex_tax:"31.4600",price_inc_tax:"37.7500",price_tax:"6.2900",base_total:"31.4600",total_ex_tax:"31.4600",total_inc_tax:"37.7500",total_tax:"6.2900",weight:"1.0000",width:"0.0000",height:"0.0000",depth:"0.0000",quantity:1,base_cost_price:"0.0000",cost_price_inc_tax:"0.0000",cost_price_ex_tax:"0.0000",cost_price_tax:"0.0000",is_refunded:!1,quantity_refunded:0,refund_amount:"0.0000",return_id:0,wrapping_id:0,wrapping_name:"",base_wrapping_cost:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_ex_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_inc_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_message:"",quantity_shipped:0,event_name:null,event_date:"",fixed_shipping_cost:"0.0000",ebay_item_id:"",ebay_transaction_id:"",option_set_id:null,parent_order_product_id:null,is_bundled_product:!1,bin_picking_number:"",external_id:null,fulfillment_source:"",brand:"Sagaform",gift_certificate_id:null,applied_discounts:[],product_options:[],configurable_fields:[],discounted_total_inc_tax:"37.7500"}],items_total:2,items_shipped:0,shipping_method:"Free Shipping",base_cost:0,cost_ex_tax:0,cost_inc_tax:0,cost_tax:0,cost_tax_class_id:2,base_handling_cost:0,handling_cost_ex_tax:0,handling_cost_inc_tax:0,handling_cost_tax:0,handling_cost_tax_class_id:2,shipping_zone_id:2,shipping_zone_name:"Qatar"}],downloads:[{line_items:[{id:15,order_id:103,product_id:104,variant_id:72,order_pickup_method_id:0,order_address_id:0,name:"[Sample] Utility Caddy",name_customer:"[Sample] Utility Caddy",name_merchant:"[Sample] Utility Caddy",sku:"OFSUC",upc:"",type:"digital",base_price:"41.3600",price_ex_tax:"41.3600",price_inc_tax:"49.6300",price_tax:"8.2700",base_total:"41.3600",total_ex_tax:"41.3600",total_inc_tax:"49.6300",total_tax:"8.2700",weight:"0.0000",width:"0.0000",height:"0.0000",depth:"0.0000",quantity:1,base_cost_price:"0.0000",cost_price_inc_tax:"0.0000",cost_price_ex_tax:"0.0000",cost_price_tax:"0.0000",is_refunded:!1,quantity_refunded:0,refund_amount:"0.0000",return_id:0,wrapping_id:0,wrapping_name:"",base_wrapping_cost:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_ex_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_inc_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_cost_tax:"0.0000",wrapping_message:"",quantity_shipped:0,event_name:null,event_date:"",fixed_shipping_cost:"0.0000",ebay_item_id:"",ebay_transaction_id:"",option_set_id:null,parent_order_product_id:null,is_bundled_product:!1,bin_picking_number:"",external_id:null,fulfillment_source:"",brand:"OFS",gift_certificate_id:null,applied_discounts:[],product_options:[],configurable_fields:[],discounted_total_inc_tax:"49.6300"}]}],email:{gift_certificates:[]}}]};


//use flatMap to iterate over consignments array
const skuArray = jsonObject.consignments.flatMap((consignment) =>
  //concatenate sku values from shipping and downloads arrays
  consignment.shipping.concat(consignment.downloads)
    //flatten the nested arrays and extract sku values
    .flatMap((item) => item.line_items.flatMap((subItem) => subItem.sku))
);


console.log(skuArray);
```

Comment: Maybe one renames `jsonObject` to `data` in order to clearly emphasize the difference between pure data-objects and a JSON-encoded string  to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract all values of the property `sku` anywhere deep in a given object, you may iterate over the properties of an object recursively and return the values mapped to it:

```js
function findAllSKUs(obj) {
    let skus = [];

    function search(obj) {
        if (obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object') {
            Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                if (key === 'sku' && typeof value === 'string') {
                    skus.push(value);
                } else {
                    search(value);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    search(obj);
    return skus;
}

const data =
{
"id": 103,
"consignments": [
    {
        "pickups": [],
        "shipping": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "first_name": "Sabareesh",
                "line_items": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "order_id": 103,
                        "product_id": 86,
                        "variant_id": 66,
                        "order_pickup_method_id": 0,
                        "order_address_id": 4,
                        "name": "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
                        "name_customer": "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
                        "name_merchant": "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
                        "sku": "ABS",
                        "upc": "",
                        "type": "physical",
                        "base_price": "225.0000",
                        "price_ex_tax": "225.0000",
                        "price_inc_tax": "270.0000",
                        "price_tax": "45.0000",
                        "base_total": "225.0000",
                        "total_ex_tax": "225.0000",
                        "total_inc_tax": "270.0000",
                        "total_tax": "45.0000",
                        "weight": "1.0000",
                        "width": "10.0000",
                        "height": "10.0000",
                        "depth": "10.0000",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "base_cost_price": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_tax": "0.0000",
                        "is_refunded": false,
                        "quantity_refunded": 0,
                        "refund_amount": "0.0000",
                        "return_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_name": "",
                        "base_wrapping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_message": "",
                        "quantity_shipped": 0,
                        "event_name": null,
                        "event_date": "",
                        "fixed_shipping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "ebay_item_id": "",
                        "ebay_transaction_id": "",
                        "option_set_id": null,
                        "parent_order_product_id": null,
                        "is_bundled_product": false,
                        "bin_picking_number": "",
                        "external_id": null,
                        "fulfillment_source": "",
                        "brand": "",
                        "gift_certificate_id": null,
                        "applied_discounts": [],
                        "product_options": [],
                        "configurable_fields": [],
                        "discounted_total_inc_tax": "270.0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "order_id": 103,
                        "product_id": 94,
                        "variant_id": 68,
                        "order_pickup_method_id": 0,
                        "order_address_id": 4,
                        "name": "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
                        "name_customer": "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
                        "name_merchant": "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
                        "sku": "OCG",
                        "upc": "",
                        "type": "physical",
                        "base_price": "31.4600",
                        "price_ex_tax": "31.4600",
                        "price_inc_tax": "37.7500",
                        "price_tax": "6.2900",
                        "base_total": "31.4600",
                        "total_ex_tax": "31.4600",
                        "total_inc_tax": "37.7500",
                        "total_tax": "6.2900",
                        "weight": "1.0000",
                        "width": "0.0000",
                        "height": "0.0000",
                        "depth": "0.0000",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "base_cost_price": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_tax": "0.0000",
                        "is_refunded": false,
                        "quantity_refunded": 0,
                        "refund_amount": "0.0000",
                        "return_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_name": "",
                        "base_wrapping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_message": "",
                        "quantity_shipped": 0,
                        "event_name": null,
                        "event_date": "",
                        "fixed_shipping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "ebay_item_id": "",
                        "ebay_transaction_id": "",
                        "option_set_id": null,
                        "parent_order_product_id": null,
                        "is_bundled_product": false,
                        "bin_picking_number": "",
                        "external_id": null,
                        "fulfillment_source": "",
                        "brand": "Sagaform",
                        "gift_certificate_id": null,
                        "applied_discounts": [],
                        "product_options": [],
                        "configurable_fields": [],
                        "discounted_total_inc_tax": "37.7500"
                    }
                ],
                "items_total": 2,
                "items_shipped": 0,
                "shipping_method": "Free Shipping",
                "base_cost": 0,
                "cost_ex_tax": 0,
                "cost_inc_tax": 0,
                "cost_tax": 0,
                "cost_tax_class_id": 2,
                "base_handling_cost": 0,
                "handling_cost_ex_tax": 0,
                "handling_cost_inc_tax": 0,
                "handling_cost_tax": 0,
                "handling_cost_tax_class_id": 2,
                "shipping_zone_id": 2,
                "shipping_zone_name": "Qatar"      
            }
        ],
        "downloads": [
            {
                "line_items": [
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "order_id": 103,
                        "product_id": 104,
                        "variant_id": 72,
                        "order_pickup_method_id": 0,
                        "order_address_id": 0,
                        "name": "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
                        "name_customer": "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
                        "name_merchant": "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
                        "sku": "OFSUC",
                        "upc": "",
                        "type": "digital",
                        "base_price": "41.3600",
                        "price_ex_tax": "41.3600",
                        "price_inc_tax": "49.6300",
                        "price_tax": "8.2700",
                        "base_total": "41.3600",
                        "total_ex_tax": "41.3600",
                        "total_inc_tax": "49.6300",
                        "total_tax": "8.2700",
                        "weight": "0.0000",
                        "width": "0.0000",
                        "height": "0.0000",
                        "depth": "0.0000",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "base_cost_price": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "cost_price_tax": "0.0000",
                        "is_refunded": false,
                        "quantity_refunded": 0,
                        "refund_amount": "0.0000",
                        "return_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_id": 0,
                        "wrapping_name": "",
                        "base_wrapping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
                        "wrapping_message": "",
                        "quantity_shipped": 0,
                        "event_name": null,
                        "event_date": "",
                        "fixed_shipping_cost": "0.0000",
                        "ebay_item_id": "",
                        "ebay_transaction_id": "",
                        "option_set_id": null,
                        "parent_order_product_id": null,
                        "is_bundled_product": false,
                        "bin_picking_number": "",
                        "external_id": null,
                        "fulfillment_source": "",
                        "brand": "OFS",
                        "gift_certificate_id": null,
                        "applied_discounts": [],
                        "product_options": [],
                        "configurable_fields": [],
                        "discounted_total_inc_tax": "49.6300"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "email": {
            "gift_certificates": []
        }
    }
]};

const skus = findAllSKUs(data);
console.log(skus);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  id: 103,
  consignments: [
    {
      pickups: [],
      shipping: [
        {
          id: 4,
          first_name: "Sabareesh",
          line_items: [
            {
              id: 5,
              order_id: 103,
              product_id: 86,
              variant_id: 66,
              order_pickup_method_id: 0,
              order_address_id: 4,
              name: "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
              name_customer: "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
              name_merchant: "[Sample] Able Brewing System",
              sku: "ABS",
              upc: "",
              type: "physical",
              base_price: "225.0000",
              price_ex_tax: "225.0000",
              price_inc_tax: "270.0000",
              price_tax: "45.0000",
              base_total: "225.0000",
              total_ex_tax: "225.0000",
              total_inc_tax: "270.0000",
              total_tax: "45.0000",
              weight: "1.0000",
              width: "10.0000",
              height: "10.0000",
              depth: "10.0000",
              quantity: 1,
              base_cost_price: "0.0000",
              cost_price_inc_tax: "0.0000",
              cost_price_ex_tax: "0.0000",
              cost_price_tax: "0.0000",
              is_refunded: false,
              quantity_refunded: 0,
              refund_amount: "0.0000",
              return_id: 0,
              wrapping_id: 0,
              wrapping_name: "",
              base_wrapping_cost: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_ex_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_inc_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_message: "",
              quantity_shipped: 0,
              event_name: null,
              event_date: "",
              fixed_shipping_cost: "0.0000",
              ebay_item_id: "",
              ebay_transaction_id: "",
              option_set_id: null,
              parent_order_product_id: null,
              is_bundled_product: false,
              bin_picking_number: "",
              external_id: null,
              fulfillment_source: "",
              brand: "",
              gift_certificate_id: null,
              applied_discounts: [],
              product_options: [],
              configurable_fields: [],
              discounted_total_inc_tax: "270.0000",
            },
            {
              id: 14,
              order_id: 103,
              product_id: 94,
              variant_id: 68,
              order_pickup_method_id: 0,
              order_address_id: 4,
              name: "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
              name_customer: "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
              name_merchant: "[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater",
              sku: "OCG",
              upc: "",
              type: "physical",
              base_price: "31.4600",
              price_ex_tax: "31.4600",
              price_inc_tax: "37.7500",
              price_tax: "6.2900",
              base_total: "31.4600",
              total_ex_tax: "31.4600",
              total_inc_tax: "37.7500",
              total_tax: "6.2900",
              weight: "1.0000",
              width: "0.0000",
              height: "0.0000",
              depth: "0.0000",
              quantity: 1,
              base_cost_price: "0.0000",
              cost_price_inc_tax: "0.0000",
              cost_price_ex_tax: "0.0000",
              cost_price_tax: "0.0000",
              is_refunded: false,
              quantity_refunded: 0,
              refund_amount: "0.0000",
              return_id: 0,
              wrapping_id: 0,
              wrapping_name: "",
              base_wrapping_cost: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_ex_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_inc_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_message: "",
              quantity_shipped: 0,
              event_name: null,
              event_date: "",
              fixed_shipping_cost: "0.0000",
              ebay_item_id: "",
              ebay_transaction_id: "",
              option_set_id: null,
              parent_order_product_id: null,
              is_bundled_product: false,
              bin_picking_number: "",
              external_id: null,
              fulfillment_source: "",
              brand: "Sagaform",
              gift_certificate_id: null,
              applied_discounts: [],
              product_options: [],
              configurable_fields: [],
              discounted_total_inc_tax: "37.7500",
            },
          ],
          items_total: 2,
          items_shipped: 0,
          shipping_method: "Free Shipping",
          base_cost: 0,
          cost_ex_tax: 0,
          cost_inc_tax: 0,
          cost_tax: 0,
          cost_tax_class_id: 2,
          base_handling_cost: 0,
          handling_cost_ex_tax: 0,
          handling_cost_inc_tax: 0,
          handling_cost_tax: 0,
          handling_cost_tax_class_id: 2,
          shipping_zone_id: 2,
          shipping_zone_name: "Qatar",
        },
      ],
      downloads: [
        {
          line_items: [
            {
              id: 15,
              order_id: 103,
              product_id: 104,
              variant_id: 72,
              order_pickup_method_id: 0,
              order_address_id: 0,
              name: "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
              name_customer: "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
              name_merchant: "[Sample] Utility Caddy",
              sku: "OFSUC",
              upc: "",
              type: "digital",
              base_price: "41.3600",
              price_ex_tax: "41.3600",
              price_inc_tax: "49.6300",
              price_tax: "8.2700",
              base_total: "41.3600",
              total_ex_tax: "41.3600",
              total_inc_tax: "49.6300",
              total_tax: "8.2700",
              weight: "0.0000",
              width: "0.0000",
              height: "0.0000",
              depth: "0.0000",
              quantity: 1,
              base_cost_price: "0.0000",
              cost_price_inc_tax: "0.0000",
              cost_price_ex_tax: "0.0000",
              cost_price_tax: "0.0000",
              is_refunded: false,
              quantity_refunded: 0,
              refund_amount: "0.0000",
              return_id: 0,
              wrapping_id: 0,
              wrapping_name: "",
              base_wrapping_cost: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_ex_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_inc_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_cost_tax: "0.0000",
              wrapping_message: "",
              quantity_shipped: 0,
              event_name: null,
              event_date: "",
              fixed_shipping_cost: "0.0000",
              ebay_item_id: "",
              ebay_transaction_id: "",
              option_set_id: null,
              parent_order_product_id: null,
              is_bundled_product: false,
              bin_picking_number: "",
              external_id: null,
              fulfillment_source: "",
              brand: "OFS",
              gift_certificate_id: null,
              applied_discounts: [],
              product_options: [],
              configurable_fields: [],
              discounted_total_inc_tax: "49.6300",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      email: {
        gift_certificates: [],
      },
    },
  ],
};


// START actual code
const output = [];
const helperFn = (arr) => {
  arr.map((i) => {
    i.line_items.map((l) => {
      output.push(l.sku);
    });
  });
};
obj.consignments.map((c) => {
  helperFn(c.pickups);
  helperFn(c.shipping);
  helperFn(c.downloads);
});

console.log("Output: ", output);
// Output: ['ABS', 'OCG', 'OFSUC']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) can be used to process nested values :

```js
const json = '{"id":103,"consignments":[{"pickups":[],"shipping":[{"id":4,"first_name":"Sabareesh","line_items":[{"id":5,"order_id":103,"product_id":86,"variant_id":66,"order_pickup_method_id":0,"order_address_id":4,"name":"[Sample] Able Brewing System","name_customer":"[Sample] Able Brewing System","name_merchant":"[Sample] Able Brewing System","sku":"ABS","upc":"","type":"physical","base_price":"225.0000","price_ex_tax":"225.0000","price_inc_tax":"270.0000","price_tax":"45.0000","base_total":"225.0000","total_ex_tax":"225.0000","total_inc_tax":"270.0000","total_tax":"45.0000","weight":"1.0000","width":"10.0000","height":"10.0000","depth":"10.0000","quantity":1,"base_cost_price":"0.0000","cost_price_inc_tax":"0.0000","cost_price_ex_tax":"0.0000","cost_price_tax":"0.0000","is_refunded":false,"quantity_refunded":0,"refund_amount":"0.0000","return_id":0,"wrapping_id":0,"wrapping_name":"","base_wrapping_cost":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_ex_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_inc_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_message":"","quantity_shipped":0,"event_name":null,"event_date":"","fixed_shipping_cost":"0.0000","ebay_item_id":"","ebay_transaction_id":"","option_set_id":null,"parent_order_product_id":null,"is_bundled_product":false,"bin_picking_number":"","external_id":null,"fulfillment_source":"","brand":"","gift_certificate_id":null,"applied_discounts":[],"product_options":[],"configurable_fields":[],"discounted_total_inc_tax":"270.0000"},{"id":14,"order_id":103,"product_id":94,"variant_id":68,"order_pickup_method_id":0,"order_address_id":4,"name":"[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater","name_customer":"[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater","name_merchant":"[Sample] Oak Cheese Grater","sku":"OCG","upc":"","type":"physical","base_price":"31.4600","price_ex_tax":"31.4600","price_inc_tax":"37.7500","price_tax":"6.2900","base_total":"31.4600","total_ex_tax":"31.4600","total_inc_tax":"37.7500","total_tax":"6.2900","weight":"1.0000","width":"0.0000","height":"0.0000","depth":"0.0000","quantity":1,"base_cost_price":"0.0000","cost_price_inc_tax":"0.0000","cost_price_ex_tax":"0.0000","cost_price_tax":"0.0000","is_refunded":false,"quantity_refunded":0,"refund_amount":"0.0000","return_id":0,"wrapping_id":0,"wrapping_name":"","base_wrapping_cost":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_ex_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_inc_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_message":"","quantity_shipped":0,"event_name":null,"event_date":"","fixed_shipping_cost":"0.0000","ebay_item_id":"","ebay_transaction_id":"","option_set_id":null,"parent_order_product_id":null,"is_bundled_product":false,"bin_picking_number":"","external_id":null,"fulfillment_source":"","brand":"Sagaform","gift_certificate_id":null,"applied_discounts":[],"product_options":[],"configurable_fields":[],"discounted_total_inc_tax":"37.7500"}],"items_total":2,"items_shipped":0,"shipping_method":"Free Shipping","base_cost":0,"cost_ex_tax":0,"cost_inc_tax":0,"cost_tax":0,"cost_tax_class_id":2,"base_handling_cost":0,"handling_cost_ex_tax":0,"handling_cost_inc_tax":0,"handling_cost_tax":0,"handling_cost_tax_class_id":2,"shipping_zone_id":2,"shipping_zone_name":"Qatar"}],"downloads":[{"line_items":[{"id":15,"order_id":103,"product_id":104,"variant_id":72,"order_pickup_method_id":0,"order_address_id":0,"name":"[Sample] Utility Caddy","name_customer":"[Sample] Utility Caddy","name_merchant":"[Sample] Utility Caddy","sku":"OFSUC","upc":"","type":"digital","base_price":"41.3600","price_ex_tax":"41.3600","price_inc_tax":"49.6300","price_tax":"8.2700","base_total":"41.3600","total_ex_tax":"41.3600","total_inc_tax":"49.6300","total_tax":"8.2700","weight":"0.0000","width":"0.0000","height":"0.0000","depth":"0.0000","quantity":1,"base_cost_price":"0.0000","cost_price_inc_tax":"0.0000","cost_price_ex_tax":"0.0000","cost_price_tax":"0.0000","is_refunded":false,"quantity_refunded":0,"refund_amount":"0.0000","return_id":0,"wrapping_id":0,"wrapping_name":"","base_wrapping_cost":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_ex_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_inc_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_cost_tax":"0.0000","wrapping_message":"","quantity_shipped":0,"event_name":null,"event_date":"","fixed_shipping_cost":"0.0000","ebay_item_id":"","ebay_transaction_id":"","option_set_id":null,"parent_order_product_id":null,"is_bundled_product":false,"bin_picking_number":"","external_id":null,"fulfillment_source":"","brand":"OFS","gift_certificate_id":null,"applied_discounts":[],"product_options":[],"configurable_fields":[],"discounted_total_inc_tax":"49.6300"}]}],"email":{"gift_certificates":[]}}]}';

const result = [];

const obj = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => ( k === 'sku' && result.push(v), v ));

console.log( result );
```

Comment: Wow, how does this work can you explain.. Without looping or without filtering it is working

Comment: @Sabareesh The reviver function is called for each parsed key and value pair and uses the function result as the value. The links in my answer have some examples.